# How do I manage TCP Client read/write overlap issues?

Tags: multithreading, sockets, tcp, thread-safety, labview

I have a TCP client communicating with a LabVIEW GUI.

My program calls `connect()` at the start and `disconnect()` at the end. It will call `passCommand(x)` to read or write data to the LabVIEW GUI. However, in some cases, I have multiple threads which may be calling `passCommand()` and somehow the return data will get mixed up.

For example, in the main thread I will ask for the voltage, which should be a number between 300 and 400. In a different thread I will ask for the temperature, which should be a number from 0-100. The voltage will be returned as 25, while the temperature will get 250.

Is this a known issue with TCP communication and threading? Is there a way to solve this such as implementing a queue or unique id or something?

```
import socket as _socket

# get python major version as integer
from sys import version as pythonVersion
pythonVersionMajor = int(pythonVersion[0])

_serverHost = 'localhost'
_serverPort = 50007
isConnected = 0
_sockobj = None
_error_string = "error:"


def connect():
    'opens a connection to LabVIEW Server'
    global _sockobj, isConnected
    _sockobj = _socket.socket(_socket.AF_INET, _socket.SOCK_STREAM)      # create socket
    _sockobj.connect((_serverHost, _serverPort))   # connect to LV
    isConnected = 1


def disconnect():
    'closes the connection to LabVIEW Server'
    global isConnected
    _sockobj.close()                             # close socket
    isConnected = 0


def passCommand(command):
    'passes a command to LabVIEW Server'

    ## We prepend the command length (8 char long) to the message and send it to LV
    # Compute message length and pad with 0 on the left if required
    commandSize=str(len(command)).rjust(8,'0')
    # Prepend msg size to msg
    completeCommand=commandSize+command
    # python 3 requires data to be encoded
    if (pythonVersionMajor >= 3):
        completeCommand = str.encode(completeCommand)
    # Send complete command
    _sockobj.send(completeCommand)
    data = _sockobj.recv(11565536)
    # python 3 requires data to be decoded
    if (pythonVersionMajor >= 3):
        data = bytes.decode(data)
    if data.rfind(_error_string) == 0:
        error = True
        data = data[len(_error_string):] # get data after "error:" string
    else:
        error = False
    execString = "lvdata = " + data
    exec(execString, globals())
    if error:
        raise _LabVIEWError(lvdata)
    else:
        return lvdata


class _Error(Exception):
    """Base class for exceptions in this module."""
    pass


class _LabVIEWError(_Error):
    """Exception raised for errors generated in LabVIEW.

    Attributes:
        code -- LabVIEW Error Code
        source -- location of the error
        message -- explanation of the error
    """

    def __init__(self, error):
        self.code = error[0]
        self.source = error[1]        
        self.message = error[2]

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % (self.message,)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an example of one of the most common problems with threading. You are accessing a resource from multiple threads and the resource is not considered thread-safe (if both threads are sending/receiving at the same time, it's possible for a thread to get the wrong response, or even *both* responses).

Ideally you should be locking access to passCommand with a mutex so it can only be used with by one thread at a time, or opening one socket per thread, or doing all of your socket operations in a single thread.

Comment: added mutex, slows things down slightly but it solves the problem. Thanks